# Through the router i want to change the content which i have inserted in routes but when i click the button it is not changing the component, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

```
<AppBarFunc companyTitle1={companyTitle1} companyTitle2={companyTitle2} />
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomeBody} />
        <Route exact path='/Programming' render={() => <h1>Hello world</h1>} />
        <Route exact path='/Aptitude' render={() => <h1>Working</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
<Footer />
```

> This is in app.js of reactproject/src/

```
<Router>
          {
            props.allItems.map((value, index) => {
              return <span key={index}>
                <Link to={value[1]} style={{ textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>
                  <StyledMenuItem >
                    <Typography variant="caption"
                      color='textPrimary'
                    >
                      {value[0]}
                    </Typography>
                  </StyledMenuItem>
                </Link>
              </span>
            })
          }
</Router>
```

> value[0] is the button in navigation and value[1] is the path
> ex: const values = [["Programming", "/programmingArticle"], ["English", "/englishArticle"], ["Aptitude", "/aptitudeArticle"]];

> The problem is when i click button the content in the middle is not changing. When i do the refresh then it is working.

> The code in the 2nd section is 4-5 levels down to AppBar Component.

> Lastly there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2nd section of code in the question, i defined Router again, so the content was not changing while the URL is. In 1st section of code put all the components inside the router.
That's it.